# Why Can't I Touch Draw a Square on to the HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a square with html5, js and touch events, but nothing shows up when I try to draw on the canvas. What am I doing wrong?

---

Here's the code I have...

Javascript:

---

```
function square()
{   
    var can = document.getElementById('canvasSignature');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');


can.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false);

function onTouchStart(e) {
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);   

}
}
```

HTML5:

---

```
<div id="canvasDiv">
    <canvas id="canvasSignature" width="580px" height="788px" style="border:2px solid #000; background: #FFF;"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="Square">  
    <p><button onclick="square();">Square</button></p>
</div>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: That's not help. I need real help... like a tutorial, not a lecture on how to formulate questions lol. I think my question is quite clear enough. Please, can somebody help me figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks fine; can you set up and share a non-working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your  code?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into an HTML document and it worked fine. I think you'll need to provide more context.

Comment: Are you testing using a mobile browser? "touchstart" will not work on a desktop browser. Your code seems to work fine in my Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I copied and pasted your code and tested it out. It seems to be working fine in my Android phone.

Comment: The second `var can` is a duplicate of the first one — doesn't seem like much point to it.

Comment: @Chuck, you are right. In fact, I tried original posters code and couldn't reproduce the problem. I retracted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you have two functions inside each other which is causing some sort of interpretation error, because my error console says it could not find the function square().

http://jsfiddle.net/GkL7P/4/

I edited it a bit by moving the variables outside and separating the two functions...

Comment: While avoiding functions-within-functions is almost certainly a good design decision in this case, it doesn't seem to be breaking his code.  See http://jsfiddle.net/Q4DSq/ for a functional version with all code inside of `square()`.  (Or does this break in your browser?  Maybe it's a cross-compat issue.)

Comment: Maybe his code is working he has something else on the page that is breaking the script... the square(); could be a X-Compat issue in JSFiddle... I guess he should check over his ENTIRE Page again...

Comment: I tried both suggested jsfiddle websites, but on both, the square still doesn't appear when I try to draw it:( Does it work on your computers?

Comment: You have to try it on a touch supported device because the square is only being draw on touch ._.

Comment: Soo, everything's fine then? My code works fine on a touch device?

Comment: Yes... That is what the touchstart event detects... What your code does currently is set an function to handle the touch event. That function ( which draws the square) is only being called after the button is clicked and then the canvas is touched. Got it?